# No related questions are displayed (Updated)

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions

Currently no related questions are displayed at the right hand bar.

Is it just a technical problem or does it have another reason?

An example has been attached.

Updated: The problem has recurred again.

---

[image]

Comment: The bug report on [meta.se]: [The list of related questions is shown empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350569). (There wasn't much response fo far.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Although Ive searched for similar question I´havn´t found that one. Anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: Still an issue one week later. Just about to ask a question but found this

Comment: @Omnomnomnom And no feedback at the linked question as well.  

Comment: I thought something on my end was blocking it from being displayed, but I guess it's just broken.

Comment: Why this is not fixed? It is very annoying.

Comment: There's still no response on MSE, but at least it's got the status-review tag, so the devs know it's an issue. But it'd be nice to get *some* feedback...

Comment: This is now [status-completed] on the [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350569) that [Martin](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) linked to in [this comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32081/no-related-questions-are-displayed#comment142544_32081).

Comment: Regarding the update, it appears to be a regression of an earlier bug, and not related to the bug which just got fixed. See this [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) post: [The “Related” section in the right sidebar is now completely missing for new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352855).