# "Related questions" have returned?

Tags: discussion, related-questions

I was very pleased, just now, after clicking on some questions, to see the return of the column of "Related questions", which seemed to disappear for some time.  Was this a bug that was fixed? Or was the absence of "Related questions" a trial?  Perhaps this was resolved earlier than I noticed, but I'm glad it was resolved.

In any case, I primarily want to express my enthusiasm for its return as a column on the right side of a question.  Thanks to developers for returning this feature, which has long been invaluable in helping us quickly find some of the more obvious potential duplicates.

Comment: So it seems that the related question disappeared on July 9 and reappeared on July 30 (or around that date). Since August 10 there were no related question on new questions and this was fixed only recently. There are also the bug reports: [No related questions are displayed (Updated)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32081) (on this meta) and also the bug reports on [meta.se]: [The list of related questions is shown empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350569) ...

Comment: ... and [The “Related” section in the right sidebar is now completely missing for new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352855). (The latter is linked also in the accepted answer.)

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSleziak for the information and links.

Comment: I think it's gone again

Comment: aaand its back.$ {}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 11):

This was a bug that was fixed.

See [The related section of the right sidebar is now completely missing for new questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352855/the-related-section-in-the-right-sidebar-is-now-completely-missing-for-new-que).

It was an issue with their database.